# Trying to get multiple elements in flutter driver(QA environment)

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

I have been successfully using commonfinders to get a single element in flutter driver but when it comes to multiple elements which may have the same type, it always throws up an error. I understand this is by design. I would be grateful if someone could suggest a way to get multiple elements and store them in an array/list, So I can access them through their index. A similar functionality would be, in selenium, where it lets you use findElements(...) for multiple elements in contrast to findElement(...) which lets you search a single element.

Answer (score 5):

This is how to get first of elements by its type

```
find.descendant(
      of: find.byValueKey(parentWidgetKey),
      matching: find.byType('CheckBox'),
      firstMatchOnly: true,
);
```

If you have multiple checkboxes, just assign a key to their parent, get the parent by key, get the checkbox by type and set the `firstMatchOnly` flag to `true`

Answer (score 2):

The finders in flutter_driver are currently quite limited, in contrast to the finders provided by flutter_test.  This is a known issue that will presumably be addressed someday: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12810

In the meantime, as the ticket suggests, if you can assign a predictable key to your elements (e.g. `my-el-01`, `my-el-02`, `my-el-03`) then you can write a helper (`findMyEl(String prefix, int maxEls)`) that will try to find all the elements named per that scheme, and return as a list. :/